# "Show Package Contents" of iPhone build release reveals blank PNGs?

Tags: iphone, build, png

So I successfully completed my first iPhone release build and when I curiously went to "Show Package Contents" of the freshly-baked .app file, I noticed that all the contained PNGs are blank! They are all set to the appropriate resolutions, but when I open them, there's nothing to see but the default Preview.app grey.

I tried opening other .app "package contents" (from OS X apps) to see if their PNGs were visible and sure enough they were. So is this business as usual for an iPhone .app build or did I miss a gotcha?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XCode may optimize pngs when building application - those files cannot be viewed in Preview app. See "Compress PNG Files" setting in your target (in Packaging block) - if it is set to YES then that's the case.

P.S. you can revert this optimization using pngcrush tool, see command-line command for that [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/undo-xcode-png-optimizations-using-pngcrush.html)

Comment: I wish there was some app that could read the dang things out though... Apple should have used standard compression.

Comment: Sure enough, that's the case. For sake of completing the thought, I unchecked the Compression option and rebuilt to find all PNGs visible. Will switch it back, though. Thanks for aiding in my sanity check.

Comment: actually you can manually undo that compression using pngcrush tool - that way you can see compressed image resources of any app