# Icons in distribution application bundle for iPhone are blank

Tags: iphone, icons, distribution, monodevelop

I've set all the icons to use in MonoDevelop (including the correct resolutions). The icon for my app shows up in the simulator correctly as it does show up correctly on my iPhone device.

However after I build the app for distribution I've noticed when I browse the .app package has blank png files titled 'icon', so there's a blacnk Icon-small.png, Icon-Small@2x.png, Icon@2x.png and Icon.png.

I'm guessing these icons sould actually be the icon images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works on the device, I believe the contents of the app package are encrypted so that if you view it on your mac you won't see anything. The encryption would have to be stripped for you to see the contents.

**Edit:** I don't know if this actually true though - I looked at an ad-hoc build I have here and I see the same blank icons, however I do see dimension information (60x60) when I get-info in Finder. Presumably if it couldn't read the file at all, it wouldn't be able to see the dimension information? Also I can read the plists in the app just fine.

The answer is in another SO post: ["Show Package Contents" of iPhone build release reveals blank PNGs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116106/show-package-contents-of-iphone-build-release-reveals-blank-pngs)